# pageobject - when_visible for all elements

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using a combination of `cucumber` and `pageobject` to test my web application. Sometimes, the script tries to click an element even before the page that contains the element starts loading. (I confirmed this by capturing the screenshots of failing scenarios)

This inconsistency is not wide-spread and it happens repeatedly only for a few elements. Instead of directly accessing those elements, if I do `example_element.when_visible.click`, the test suite always passes.

As of now, I click a link using `link_name` (generated by pageobject module on calling `link(:name, identifier: {index: 0}, &block)`

I would like to not edit the above mentioned snippet, but act as if i called `link_name_element.when_visible.click`. The reason is, the test suite is pretty large and it would be tedious to change all the occurences and I also believe that the functionality is already present and somehow I don't see it anywhere. Can anybody help me out?!

Comment: I do not think there is a built-in way to do this. Do you need to do `when_present` before every command or just when clicking elements?

Comment: i would like to do it before every command, if that is possible

Comment: Are you using Watir or Selenium as your driver?

Comment: I am using the Watir-webdriver

Comment: Can you show your page-object classes?

Comment: it is an internal corporate project and my manager says that the code needs to remain confidential. 

This is a mock of the setup that we have

`Page` class includes the `PageObject` module and it also holds the `Browser instance` to initialize the `pageobject`. Every page representing class inherits from the above mentioned class. 

`class Menu < Page

   link(:buy, {link_text: 'buy from the source'})

 end`

The link, `buy` is one of the places where the script breaks frequently when I try to click!! It fails around 3 of 10 times and it one of the very first step in all the files!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems solution seems quite hacky and may not be considering some edge cases. However, I will share it since there are no other answers yet.

You can add the following monkey patch assuming that you are using watir-webdriver. This would be added after you require page-object.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

module PageObject
  module Platforms
    module WatirWebDriver
      class PageObject
        def find_watir_element(the_call, type, identifier, tag_name=nil)
          identifier, frame_identifiers, wait = parse_identifiers(identifier, type, tag_name)
          the_call, identifier = move_element_to_css_selector(the_call, identifier)

          if wait
            element = @browser.instance_eval "#{nested_frames(frame_identifiers)}#{the_call}.when_present"
          else
            element = @browser.instance_eval "#{nested_frames(frame_identifiers)}#{the_call}"
          end
          switch_to_default_content(frame_identifiers)
          type.new(element, :platform => :watir_webdriver)
        end        

        def process_watir_call(the_call, type, identifier, value=nil, tag_name=nil)
          identifier, frame_identifiers, wait = parse_identifiers(identifier, type, tag_name)
          the_call, identifier = move_element_to_css_selector(the_call, identifier)

          if wait
            modified_call = the_call.dup.insert(the_call.rindex('.'), '.when_present')
            value = @browser.instance_eval "#{nested_frames(frame_identifiers)}#{modified_call}"
          else
            value = @browser.instance_eval "#{nested_frames(frame_identifiers)}#{the_call}"
          end

          switch_to_default_content(frame_identifiers)
          value
        end

        def parse_identifiers(identifier, element, tag_name=nil)
          wait = identifier.has_key?(:wait) ? false : true
          identifier.delete(:wait)

          frame_identifiers = identifier.delete(:frame)
          identifier = add_tagname_if_needed identifier, tag_name if tag_name
          identifier = element.watir_identifier_for identifier
          return identifier, frame_identifiers, wait
        end        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, the intent of this patch is that the Watir `when_present` method is always called. For example, your page object call will get translated to Watir as `browser.link.when_present.click`. In theory, it should get called for any method called on a page object element.

Unfortunately, there is a catch. There are some situations where you probably do not want to wait for the element to become present. For example, when doing `page.link_element.when_not_visible`, you would not want to wait for the element to appear before checking that it does not appear. In these cases, you can force the standard behaviour of not waiting by including `:wait => false` in the element locator:

```
page.link_element(:wait => false).when_not_visible
```

Comment: i believe you meant to type `link(:example_link, {id: 'ex_link', wait: false})` because `page.link_element` doesn't take any arguments as far as I know. Set me right if I am wrong

Comment: `page.link_element` does take arguments - see the [nested elements doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/NestedElements#link_element-instance_method). Note that this example was when using the `link_element` for locating nested elements. If you were doing it in the page object accessor, your example is correct.

Comment: Using `when_present` breaks my test suite when I check for the presence of an element that does not belong in the page using the `?` method because instead of returning false when not present, it raises an error. To set this right I coded up my own wait method that always returns self (as soon as the element comes into presence or timesout if the element doesn't) and then calling `exists?` works. This does not break any of the functionality to the best of my knowledge

Comment: i always checked [this](http://rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/frames) for documentation and the NestedElements module lists only one method!! Strange!!